# Get generic list from object (over reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection

I query some data via reflection. The returned data type is System.data.datacolumn[] (variable "test"). I would like to convert it into a generic list (e.g. string List). Is that possible?

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetStringList(string property)
{
   var test =  GetPropertyValue(SomeObject, property);

    // MAGIC //

   return test;
}


public object GetPropertyValue(object obj, string propertyName)
{
    var propertyNames = propertyName.Split('.');

    foreach (var t in propertyNames)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(t);
            obj = propertyInfo != null ? propertyInfo.GetValue(obj) : null;
        }
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: What should the result of that be? A `DataColumn` contains no useful data by itself, save perhaps for the `.ColumnName`. If you're trying to extract data from a `DataTable` specifically, there are probably better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
if (test is IEnumerable) {
    var values = test as IEnumerable;

    //Method 1: convert to list
    var asList = values.Cast<object>().ToList();

    //Method 2: iterate to IEnumerable and add to List
    var asList = new List<object>();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        asList.Add(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `ToList()` method for `IEnumerable`

Comment: @canton7, try `values.Cast<object>().ToList();`